# How can I see the details of Total banned of Fail2Ban?

Tags: linux, ssh, fail2ban

I installed Fail2Ban as IDS in my server

```
/home/bheng/app/(master*) # fail2ban-client status sshd                                                   root@b-world 
Status for the jail: sshd
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed:     50
|  `- File list:        /var/log/auth.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |- Total banned:     31
   `- Banned IP list:
```

I see this

> Total banned:     31

I want to see what IP are they, so I can geolocate where they're from.

What is the command to see them ?

I've tried

> cat /var/log/auth.log | grep ip

and

> cat /var/log/auth.log | grep ban

I got nothing.

Any hints would be much appreciated.

---

I tried

> awk '($(NF-1) = /Ban/){print $NF}' /var/log/fail2ban.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -n

I got nothing.

I tried

> cat /var/log/fail2ban.log

I got

> 2021-10-31 00:00:07,323 fail2ban.server         [857]: INFO    rollover performed on /var/log/fail2ban.log

Comment: I googled "fail2ban log" and got this as the 2nd hit: https://serverfault.com/questions/841183/how-to-show-all-banned-ip-with-fail2ban. This was the first: https://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/fail2ban-log/  please make sure you've googled the problem first before posting here.

Comment: I tried this `awk '($(NF-1) = /Ban/){print $NF}' /var/log/fail2ban.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -n` I got nothing as a result which make no sense.

Comment: What happens if you look at `/var/log/fail2ban.log*` as detailed in @schroeder 's second link?

Comment: Try `awk '($(NF-1) = /Ban/){print $NF}' /var/log/fail2ban.log* | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`

Comment: @camp0 Note that the older log files are compressed. The solution given was to use `zgrep`.

Comment: well on fedora works but if zgrep helps happy to know that :)

Answer (score 1):

On many distributions, Fail2Ban records every action it performs to the SYSLOG. You can double-check your **/etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf** and look for the command **logtarget**. On my CENTOS box, that line reads:

```
logtarget = SYSLOG
```

If that case, you can see every action (ban, or unban) in the message log: **/var/log/messages**

You can view every action Fail2Ban makes with the following command:

```
grep "fail2ban" /var/log/messages
```

If you want to extract only the IPs, try the following command:

```
grep "fail2ban" /var/log/messages | grep " Ban " | cut -d" " -f10 | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy as:

```bash
$ sudo grep -w "Ban" /var/log/fail2ban.log                                            
2024-03-30 23:30:33,009 fail2ban.actions        [6398]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 47.92.145.154
2024-03-30 23:31:07,225 fail2ban.actions        [6398]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 124.222.23.243
```